# Questions showing up multiple times, when browsing unanswered questions

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

I have lots of these duplicated questions in the list right now, when browsing unanswered questions. In each case, every question that shows up multiple times has working links/forwarding.

This only seems to happen, when i browse unanswered question, with no answers. Like in the following screenshot.

[image: Image of the selected filter]

### Update

Thanks [keyur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7832176/keyur-potdar) for providing that generic link.

> This seems to be happening for many tags (or all of them?). I was
>   going to post the same thing. The generic link is
>   https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/xxx?tab=noanswers (where
>   xxx is the tag).

### Examples

[image: One example of many]

[image: another example]

Comment: This seems to be happening for many tags (or all of them?). I was going to post the same thing. The generic link is  `https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/xxx?tab=noanswers` (where xxx is the tag).

Comment: I'll add this information (happening for many tags) into the question.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior with the CSS tag in Unanswered Questions under [No Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/css?tab=noanswers). [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGK2S.png). The duplicate listing continues to persist after several minutes, despite refreshing.